# Display grid of images in Android with center of grid layout being empty?

Tags: java, android

I have a decent amount of images(10 or so) that I need to display in grid form with the center of the layout being empty. Currently I'm adding each image through code but that is becoming time consuming. Every image is using the same onTouchListener class. The center of the layout needs to be empty to accommodate a "container" image view that selected images can be dragged and dropped onto. I thought of using an image adapter but only saw examples that were for a gallery type view in either horizontal or vertical orientation. Is there any way to create a custom class that automatically positions the images in grid form with an empty center that has predetermined dimensions?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a `RecyclerView` with `GridLayoutManager`, then you can get the firstVisisbleItem and lastVisibleItem. This should give you the number of visibleItems with which you can decide the index in the grid where you should not show any item. This would require you to take care of some implementation level details, but the basic logic should be like this only. Hope it helps.

Comment: I just found [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-gridview-layout-tutorial/) and was considering taking that approach but I'm not sure how I would insert my custom class as one of the int or column/row items

Comment: you probably need to implement heterogeneous recycler view. See [this](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Heterogenous-Layouts-inside-RecyclerView) link.

Comment: Interesting. I've never heard of that before. Could that be done with a GridView as well do you think?

Comment: BTW, I'm using a RelativeLayout with a GridLayout

Comment: I don't know. But I would recommend you to use a recycler view with grid layout instead of going for gridlayout. Believe me, it is very easy using recyclerview, you just need to change the layout manager, everything else would be same.

Comment: Ok. So after looking over that link you provided, I'm trying to figure out how I would define my custom class as one of the viewholders. My custom "container" class extends RelativeLayout.

Comment: Just create two ViewHolder classes. Both of them will inflate different kinds of layouts. Based of which layout is inflated in which ViewHolder, you can bind the corresponding views of that layout to the correct variables in the ViewHolder. Then in getView(), check for the type of ViewHolder and according write your logic to handle it.